# Cache Rust dependencies with Docker build

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, actix-web

I have hello world web project in Rust + Actix-web. I have several problems. First is every change in code causes recompiling whole project including downloading and compiling every crate. I'd like to work like in normal development - it means cache compiled crates and only recompile my codebase. Second problem is it doesn't expose my my app. It's unreachable via web browser

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust

WORKDIR /var/www/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

RUN cargo run
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: hello-world
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/app
      - registry:/root/.cargo/registry

volumes:
  registry:
    driver: local
```

main.rs:

```
extern crate actix_web;

use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, Responder};

fn index() -> impl Responder {
    "Hello world"
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(web::resource("/").to(index)))
        .bind("0.0.0.0:8080")?
        .run()
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "hello-world"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = []
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
actix-web = "1.0"
```

Comment: please provide your cargo.toml as well

Comment: Your Dockerfile is missing a `CMD` line; what's the container supposed to run when it starts up?  (Is the build sequence actually completing?)

Comment: If the answer solved your question please accept it or provide additional information to further debug the issue at hand

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Seems like you are not alone in your endeavor to cache rust dependencies via the docker build process. Here is a great article that helps you along the way: https://blog.mgattozzi.dev/caching-rust-docker-builds/

The gist of it is you need a dummy.rs and your Cargo.toml first, then build it to cache the dependencies and then copy your application source later in order to not invalidate the cache with every build.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rust
WORKDIR /var/www/app
COPY dummy.rs .
COPY Cargo.toml .
RUN sed -i 's#src/main.rs#dummy.rs#' Cargo.toml
RUN cargo build --release
RUN sed -i 's#dummy.rs#src/main.rs#' Cargo.toml
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release
CMD ["target/release/app"]
```

CMD application name "app" is based on what you have specified in your Cargo.toml for your binary.

**dummy.rs**

```
fn main() {}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "app"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["..."]
[[bin]]
name = "app"
path = "src/main.rs"

[dependencies]
actix-web = "1.0.0"
```

**src/main.rs**

```
extern crate actix_web;

use actix_web::{web, App, HttpServer, Responder};

fn index() -> impl Responder {
    "Hello world"
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(web::resource("/").to(index)))
        .bind("0.0.0.0:8080")?
        .run()
}
```

Comment: Great answer. For reference, `COPY dummy.rs` can be replaced by `RUN echo "fn main() {}" > dummy.rs`, which avoids having a file `dummy.rs` on the repository.

Comment: Instead of manipulating the `Cargo.toml` you could add a 2nd `[[bin]]` target to it. Make sure to copy `src/dummy.rs` together with your `Cargo.toml`. Then add a 2nd bin target (like lines 5-7 fro your example). Set  `name= "download-only"`, `path = "src/dummy.rs"` and call `cargo build --bin download-only`.

Comment: If you're doing `RUN echo "fn main() {}" > ./src/main.rs`, then `COPY ./src ./src`, cargo may not rebuild your app. You'll need to update the last modified of the main.rs file to inform cargo to rebuild it.
Before your 2nd cargo build, you need to run `RUN touch -a -m ./src/main.rs` to update the last modified of the file.

Comment: @MartinSommer the `[[bin]]` approach doesn't work. For your binary `download-only`, you'll need to `cargo build --bin download-only`, which will make docker cache dependencies only for this command. However, you'll still need to `cargo build --bin app`, which won't be cached. The only way for docker to cache properly is if both the build commands are exactly the same, so I don't think there's an alternative to manipulating `Cargo.toml`

Comment: I have found it useful to use the `--offline` flag too to make sure that cargo doesn't attempt to refresh its dependencies as part of the standard build. Though for some reason I'm using `cargo install --offline --path .` instead of `build` but I assume it applies to build too.

Comment: My cargo.toml didn't have a main.rs in it, and incorporating some of the other comments, I came up with this version that does not need sed or dummy.rs.  Docker caches by content so I don't think you need any special touch command.
    `RUN mkdir src`
    `RUN echo "fn main() {}" > ./src/main.rs`
    `COPY ["Cargo.toml", "Cargo.lock",  "./"]`
    `RUN cargo build --release`
    `COPY src src`
    `RUN cargo build --release`

Comment: @casret I can confirm this works, at least in my case. This is an awesome improvement over other solutions posted here; you might want to post this as a first-class answer to the original question.

Comment: @Ixg glad that it helped you, I posted it.  BTW, I was wrong and the touch is needed for the reason laid out by Ari, I included that in the post.

Comment: The original blog.mgatozzi.dev article is now 404. The Wayback Machine is your friend: https://web.archive.org/web/20221028051630/https://blog.mgattozzi.dev/caching-rust-docker-builds/

Comment: This approach, unfortunately, fails for bigger projects with workspaces. In such a case, cargo chef as explained below is a good option.

Comment: `RUN touch -t 8001031305 /rust/server/src/main.rs` is also sometimes useful

Comment: The article by Michael Gattozzi was moved here: https://dev.to/mgattozzi/plumbing-the-deps-of-the-crate-caching-rust-docker-builds-2e48

Answer (score 34):

With the (still experimental) Docker Buildkit you can finally properly cache build folders during a `docker build` step:

**Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
from rust
ENV HOME=/home/root
WORKDIR $HOME/app
[...]
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/root/app/target \
    cargo build --release
```

Then run:

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . --progress=plain`

Subsequent docker builds will reuse the cargo and target folders from cache, hence massively speeding up your builds.

To clear the docker cache mount: `docker builder prune --filter type=exec.cachemount`

If you don't see proper caching: Make sure to confirm the location of your cargo/registry and target folders in the docker image, if you don't see proper caching.

Minimal working Example: https://github.com/benmarten/sccache-docker-test/tree/no-sccache

Comment: Won't using `--mount=type=cache,target=/home/rust/src/target` mean that other simultaneous builds access the `target` directory? Should `sharing=private` or `sharing=locked` be added to that cache line? Perhaps in combination with a separate layer to populate a build local `target/` from the cache and another layer to push the new stuff back into the cache?

Comment: If you're using multi-stage build and need copy something from cache (for example built executable binary) you have to copy it out of the cache. For exmaple please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64141061/4183352

Answer (score 16):

You can use `cargo-chef` (unrelated to the Chef DevOps tool) to leverage Docker layer caching using a multi-stage build.

```
FROM rust as planner
WORKDIR app
# We only pay the installation cost once, 
# it will be cached from the second build onwards
RUN cargo install cargo-chef 
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare  --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM rust as cacher
WORKDIR app
RUN cargo install cargo-chef
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM rust as builder
WORKDIR app
COPY . .
# Copy over the cached dependencies
COPY --from=cacher /app/target target
RUN cargo build --release --bin app

FROM rust as runtime
WORKDIR app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/app /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["./usr/local/bin/app"]
```

It does not require Buildkit and works for both simple projects and workspaces.
You can find more details in the [release announcement](https://www.lpalmieri.com/posts/fast-rust-docker-builds/).

Comment: Won't using `--mount=type=cache,target=/home/rust/src/target` mean that other simultaneous builds access the `target` directory? Should `sharing=private` or `sharing=locked` be added to that cache line? Perhaps in combination with a separate layer to populate a build local `target/` from the cache and another layer to push the new stuff back into the cache?

Comment: I am getting this error: `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "./usr/local/bin/app": stat ./usr/local/bin/app: no such file or directory: unknown.`

Comment: **Update**: I fixed the error by deleting the dot in the array value of "ENTRYPOINT".

Comment: This is nice answer. But it lack caching index of crates.io and also it takes long to copy big target directory

Answer (score 8):

While [electronix384128](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302437/electronix384128) answer is excellent. I would like to expand on it by adding cache for `.cargo/git` which is needed for any dependency using git and by adding a multistage docker example.

Using rust-musl-builder and Docker Buildkit feature, which is now default in Docker Desktop 2.4. On other versions you may still need to enable it via: `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .`

`rusl-musl-builder`'s working directory is `/home/rust/src`
Tried setting uid/gid on `--mount` but failed to compile rust due to permission issue in target.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM ekidd/rust-musl-builder:stable AS builder

COPY . .
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/rust/.cargo/git \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/home/rust/.cargo/registry \
    --mount=type=cache,sharing=private,target=/home/rust/src/target \
    sudo chown -R rust: target /home/rust/.cargo && \
    cargo build --release && \
    # Copy executable out of the cache so it is available in the final image.
    cp target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/my-executable ./my-executable

FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/my-executable .
USER 1000
CMD ["./my-executable"]
```

Comment: Won't using `--mount=type=cache,target=/home/rust/src/target` mean that other simultaneous builds access the `target` directory? Should `sharing=private` or `sharing=locked` be added to that cache line? Perhaps in combination with a separate layer to populate a build local `target/` from the cache and another layer to push the new stuff back into the cache?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have updated the example and dockerfile syntax is now no longer experimental 

Comment: Thank you for the comment you made about copying executable out of the cache. It is very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

This is a refinement of the [@ckaserer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474618/11435461) answer incorporating the comments and some personal experiences.  It does not require you create a dummy file in your repo, or edit the Cargo.toml file at build time.

```
RUN echo 'fn main() { panic!("Dummy Image Called!")}' > ./src/main.rs
COPY ["Cargo.toml", "Cargo.lock",  "./"]
RUN cargo build --release
COPY src src
#need to break the cargo cache
RUN touch ./src/main.rs
RUN cargo build --release
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on [@ckaserer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474618/4988637)'s answer, you can `RUN echo "fn main() {}" > ./src/main.rs` to build the dependencies before building your app.

First copy just your `Cargo.toml` and `Cargo.lock` files and build the dummy main.rs file:

```
FROM rust as rust-builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy Cargo files
COPY ./Cargo.toml .
COPY ./Cargo.lock .

# Create fake main.rs file in src and build
RUN mkdir ./src && echo 'fn main() { println!("Dummy!"); }' > ./src/main.rs
RUN cargo build --release
```

Then you can copy over your real src directory and run build again:

```
# Copy source files over
RUN rm -rf ./src
COPY ./src ./src

# The last modified attribute of main.rs needs to be updated manually,
# otherwise cargo won't rebuild it.
RUN touch -a -m ./src/main.rs

RUN cargo build --release
```

Then we can copy our file to a slim version of debain.
Here's the full docker file:

```
FROM rust as rust-builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./Cargo.toml .
COPY ./Cargo.lock .
RUN mkdir ./src && echo 'fn main() { println!("Dummy!"); }' > ./src/main.rs
RUN cargo build --release
RUN rm -rf ./src
COPY ./src ./src
RUN touch -a -m ./src/main.rs
RUN cargo build --release

FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=rust-builder /usr/src/app/target/release/app /usr/local/bin/
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
CMD ["app"]
```

Comment: in my case, after `RUN rm -rf ./src` i need to add `RUN rm -rf ./target/release` also

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your `volumes` definition is not doing a bind mount. I believe your current config is copying `HOST ./registry/` into `DOCKER /root/.cargo/registry/`, writing to `DOCKER /root/.cargo/registry/`, and discarding the contents when the container is shut down.

Instead, you'll want to specify the `bind` type on the volume:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: hello-world
    build: .
    environment:
      - CARGO_HOME=/var/www/
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/app
      - type: bind
        source: ./registry
        target: /root/.cargo/registry
```

However, keep in mind a `/root/.cargo/.package-cache` file is also created, but not kept here. Instead, you could change the `source` to `./.cargo` and target to `/root/.cargo`.

---

For my own (mostly cli) rust projects, I like to use a [drop-in replacement I've written for `cargo`](https://gist.github.com/0b10011/137a167bdb8ada1ecfdcd8b6aecf0e6d) that I've confirmed caches packages between builds, greatly reducing build time. This can be copied to `/usr/local/bin` to be used globally, or ran as `./cargo build` within a single project. But do keep in mind this specific script assumes the app is located at `/usr/src/app` within the container, so it'd likely need adjusting for your use.

Comment: Can you share what your Dockerfile would look like here?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do, and it's compatible with build scripts. It's a multi-stage build so it results in a small image, but caches the built dependencies in the first image.

```
FROM rust:1.43 AS builder

RUN apt-get update
RUN cd /tmp && USER=root cargo new --bin <projectname>
WORKDIR /tmp/<projectname>

# cache rust dependencies in docker layer
COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock ./
RUN touch build.rs && echo "fn main() {println!(\"cargo:rerun-if-changed=\\\"/tmp/<projectname>/build.rs\\\"\");}" >> build.rs
RUN cargo build --release

# build the real stuff and disable cache via the ADD
ADD "https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=10&format=h" skipcache
COPY ./build.rs ./build.rs

# force the build.rs script to run by modifying it
RUN echo " " >> build.rs
COPY ./src ./src
RUN cargo build --release

FROM rust:1.43
WORKDIR /bin
COPY --from=builder /tmp/<projectname>/target/release/server /bin/<project binary>
RUN chmod +x ./<project binary>
CMD ./<project binary>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem as you did, and tried multiple ways at shortening the build time by caching dependencies.

#### 1. [@ckaserer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474618/11435461) answer

It gets the job done, and with the easy-to-understand explanation of why it works, it's a great solution.
However, this boils down to preference, but if you don't cache the dependencies this way, you can follow #2.

#### 2. Use [`cargo-chef`](https://github.com/LukeMathWalker/cargo-chef)

[@LukeMathWalker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64528456/11435461), the creator himself, goes through the steps necessary to use [`cargo-chef`](https://github.com/LukeMathWalker/cargo-chef), but here's a *slightly adjusted example from the github page.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM lukemathwalker/cargo-chef:latest-rust-1.60.0 AS chef
WORKDIR /app

FROM chef as planner
COPY . .
RUN cargo chef prepare --recipe-path recipe.json

FROM chef as builder
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
# Build the dependencies (and add to docker's caching layer)
# This caches the dependency files similar to how @ckaserer's solution
# does, but is handled solely through the `cargo-chef` library.
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json
# Build the application
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release --bin emailer

FROM debian:buster-slim AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/<Name of Rust Application> /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/<Name of Rust Application>"]
```

You should notice a significant decrease in build times with the above changes!

---

Side note, as far as I know, [this blog entry](https://endler.dev/2020/rust-compile-times/), though not on dockerized builds, holds the best info on compiling rust apps faster on your local machine. You might find it helpful so I suggest checking it out if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this answer is a little late to the party, however I believe I have found a solution that is slightly different (although along the same basic idea) but that will create the build dependencies in a single Docker layer, meaning they will be cached - you can simply copy the `RUN` command layer from the following:

```
...
COPY Cargo.toml /app/

RUN mkdir src && \
    echo 'fn main() {\nprintln!("Hello, world!");\n}' > src/main.rs && \
    cargo build && \ 
    cargo clean --package $(awk '/name/ {gsub(/"/,""); print $3}' Cargo.toml | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | tr -d '\r') && \
    rm -rf src 

COPY src /app/src
...
```

First copy your `Cargo.toml` file with it's dependencies and then insert the `RUN` layer below, then afterwards copy in your actual code.

This first runs a dummy application (copied straight from `cargo init`) and this package is named the same as your project, then it runs `cargo clean` on just that package, meaning if you add your code and run the build again, all of the dependencies are cached already, and it just rebuilds your code. By combining the whole thing in a single layer it will save time should anything change further down the pipeline.